# Git Plugin is not fetching repo using jenkinsfile

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks, jenkins-git-plugin

Hy, I am using Git Plugin to fetch github code for jenkins pipeline. Actually I want to set load the branch dynamically from where the push event was triggered. Now, I have problem:

1. When I configure git plugin > using jenkins UI repo URL & credentials and specify the branch in field then webhooks are working and fetching the code from the branch specified in the "Branch Specifier" at jenkins UI, but when i remove this UI configuration and want to add below code for configuration, then job is thorowing an error:

### GIT PLUGIN CODE FOR PUBLIC REPO CONFIGURATION USED IN JENKINSFILE, Instead to use UI configuration:

(repo is public)

checkout scmGit(
branches: [[name: 'my-branch']],
userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/ws-cleanup-plugin']])

### JENKINS CONSOLE ERROR:

Started by GitHub push by alisial45
Checking out git into /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Sample Pipeline for webhooks@script/80b99c2f5bbf8b755643e9680374e300a46ad183dd90018b5a9bfe0459d1e324 to read Jenkinsfile
Seen 0 remote branches

> /usr/bin/git show-ref --tags -d # timeout=10
> ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
> ERROR: Maximum checkout retry attempts reached, aborting
> Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Is your jenkinsfile sitting in repo as well?

Comment: Yes, jenkinsfile is in my repo.

Comment: In the end of your job configuration try disabling light weight checkout

Comment: Dear, I have also tried this. Is This git plugin code is still compatible with jenkins? maybe it not supported in new veriosn?

Comment: One more thing, checkout code It is also working within jenkins job configuration, But, its not working using jenkinsfile. Maybe jenkins not fetching jenkinsfile prior to checkout in repo.